# I have 2 column 1 table and based on TABLE1_vaccinated if that is 'Yes' then change TABLE1_vaccination_status to 'vaccinated'

Tags: sql, oracle

Le1.Vaccinated = 'yes' AND table1.Dose1= IS NOT NULL (THERE IS DATA in the field) –

Comment: Please add your table definition and maybe some sample data, just so there is no confusion here.

Comment: Right; because, what you posted so far doesn't make much sense. Not that syntax is wrong, I don't understand what is what.

Comment: Your table is defined with a column "Vaccinationstatus", not "TABLE1_vaccination_status" or "Vaccination_status" - check for typos! Then you have a `WHERE =` where you need to remove that `=`

Comment: @user17659635 it should be `table1.Dose1 IS NOT NULL` (no `=` there). Please check the correct syntax in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

*Check with this code*

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    Vaccinationstatus VARCHAR(10),
    Vaccinated VARCHAR(3)
);
INSERT INTO table1 (Vaccinated)
VALUES('yes');

SELECT * From table1;

UPDATE table1
SET table1.Vaccinationstatus = 'Vaccinated'
WHERE table1.Vaccinated = 'yes'
```

Comment: You may want to explain what typos you fixed - then it's clearer for the OP where they went wrong

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @user17659635 end it properly by appending a `;`